# LazyRow's items can't be clicked right after scrolling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The LazyRow nested inside a HorizontalPager. When I scrolled the LazyRow to the end/start and tried to click one of the item inside the LazyRow right away, it didn't detect any click events after 1 or 2 seconds. Is this normal?

Here's my code:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        HorizontalPager(pageCount = 2) {
            when (it) {
                0 -> {
                    LazyRow {
                        items(20) {
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                            Box(modifier = Modifier
                                .size(60.dp)
                                .background(Color.Red)
                                .clickable { }
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                        }
                    }
                }
                1 -> {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: to reproduce the issue easier, try to scroll really fast to the end of the list and click the last item, or scroll really fast to the start of the list and click the first item.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, i hope it's just compose lib issue, will wait for the next one.

Comment: Same issue here, did you resolve it? 